# Computer turns off randomly

Tags: power-supply, shutdown, power-management, electric-shock

Desktop, custom built PC, Intel i7 UEFI, 1 NVM 1 HDD 4 SSD. Computer turns itself off randomly, a few seconds later turns back on. Replaced power cable, checked internal cabling, disconnected HDD, 2 motherboard fans, used different outlet, different surge protector. PSU 900W, 4 years old. No unusual noises from computer. Most temps are 45, 1 temp says 60. Not doing graphic intensive work. Not gaming. In Cool room. Computer has little to no dust internally. When turns off, it is sudden, no proper shutdown. Happens every few minutes, happens in Win10, Win11.
Other than replacing the PSU, what other troubleshooting steps can I take?

Comment: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86

Comment: Start it with a bootable USB key and let it run. Does it do the same thing?

Comment: How does the _electric-shock_ tag come into play?

Comment: Does it even happen when you are just on the BIOS/UEFI (Firmware Setup screen)? If possible take it to a nearby repair shop. They are likely to have spare components to swap out and retest to nail down the faulty part.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a blown cap on a PSU.